# Select data based on histogram count

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Dear all: I have a set of 2D array that looks like the following. The first 3 columns are the xyz coordinates of a point, and the third column is the point to center distance.

```
array([[-1.01742668e+01,  6.89185798e-01,  1.17535509e-01,
         2.02460059e+03],
       [-1.00412054e+01,  6.97973669e-01, -5.14677428e-02,
         2.02460887e+03],
       [-9.89616013e+00,  6.80048764e-01,  1.06134348e-01,
         2.02459041e+03],
       ...,
       [-9.60342407e+01, -2.03417969e+00, -3.64747904e-02,
         2.02402794e+03],
       [-9.71151733e+01, -2.02474523e+00,  5.34135802e-03,
         2.02408764e+03],
       [-9.60278931e+01, -2.04594707e+00, -4.45659012e-02,
         2.02401589e+03]])
```

I have plotted a histogram that looks like the following.[image]

I'm wondering is there any way to remove the data points that are associated with the bins in the red circle?

Currently what I have tried is the following code.

```
c_dist=np.asarray(c_dist)

hist, bins = np.histogram(c_dist[:,3], bins=100)
# Threshold frequency
freq = 100

# Zero out low values
hist[np.where(hist <= freq)] = 0
# Plot
width = 0.7 * (bins[1] - bins[0])
center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2
plt.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width)
# plt.yticks(np.arange(min(hist), max(hist)+1, 10))
plt.title("Center to Point Distance")
plt.xlabel("Distance")
plt.ylabel("Count")

d = np.digitize(c_dist[:,3], bins)
```

and got the following figure.

[image]

however, it looks like the method only removes the unwanted bins in the plot and could not remove the associated data points in the original dataset.

Could anyone kindly help me with this issue? Thanks a lot for your great help and support.

Comment: What do you mean could not remove the associated data points??, you have tirned them to zeros.. do you want to remove them?

Comment: You are editing the `hist` array based on a frequency filter. If you  want to edit the original data, filter the `c_dist` array.  In addition please follow guidelines and provide a [mive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean that they are zeros and you want to delete
Instead of:

```
hist[np.where(hist <= freq)] = 0
```

do the following:

```
hist = hist[hist <= freq]
```

Comment: Dear @adir abargil. Sorry for my bad explanation, and please let me try again. What I want is to find the data points (c_dist[:, 3]) that are contained in the bins (circled in red) and remove them from the original dataset (c_dist)

Comment: can you post the original dataset? or simpler, just try the other solution

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to remove rows from `c_dist` based on its third column. If that's what you need consider the following toy data example:

```
import numpy as np

c_dist = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 4))
th_freq = 4

c_dist_clean = c_dist[c_dist[:, 3] >= th_freq]
```

The last line selects the rows of `c_dist` whose values in the third column exceed `th_freq` and copies them to `c_dist_clean`.

Comment: Dear @MaxPowers. Sorry for my bad explanation, and please let me try again. What I want is to find the data points (c_dist[:, 3]) that are contained in the bins (circled in red) and remove them from the original dataset (c_dist)